# How to pass a function declared inside an object to child component

Tags: angular, eventemitter

I have a DatagridComponent which just displays some rows with data in it. This one can pass action bar items to this component as many as he wants, and pass a function with it which gets called when an items (it's simply a button) gets clicked:

**DatagridComponent:**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'llqa-datagrid',
  templateUrl: './datagrid.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./datagrid.component.css']
})
export class DatagridComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() {}

  @Input() actionBar: Array<{
    text: string,
    action: () => {}
  }>;
}
```

**datagrid.component.html:**

```
<div class="datagrid">
  <div class="datagrid-actionbar">
    <button *ngFor="let actionBarItem of actionBar"(click)="actionBarItem.action()">{{actionBarItem.text}}</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

**ParentComponent**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'llqa-parent',
  templateUrl: './parent.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./parent.component.css']
})
export class ParentComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() {}

  actionBar = [
    {
      text: "Add",
      action: () => {
        this.add()
      }
    },
    {
      text: "Delete",
      action: () => {
        this.delete()
      }
    }
  ];

  add(): void {
    // some code
  }

  delete(): void {
    // some code
  }
}
```

**parent.component.html:**

```
<llqa-datagrid [actionBar]="actionbar"></llqa-datagrid>
```

My Problem is, the function gets called, but loses the context of `ParentComponent`. So `this` would be the `DatagridComponent`. I made researches and found a way using `@Output()` with an `EventEmitter`, but this won't work in my case since the function I want to call is a property of an object. And since one should be able to add as many `actionBar` items as he wants, I can't just define `@Output()` properties, am I right?

So, how can I solve my problem?

Comment: "My Problem is, the function gets called" which function?

Answer (score 0):

I would pass actual grid instance in each action like this

`@Input() actionBar: Array<{
    text: string,
    action: (grid: DatagridComponent) => {}
  }>;`

In parent

`actionBar = [
    {
      text: "Add",
      action: (grid) => {
        grd.add()
      }
    },
    {
      text: "Delete",
      action: (grid) => {
        grid.delete()
      }
    }
  ];`

I like this way because you are getting types information and there is no magical this reference.